# Пропала вкладка UI Unity

Tags: unity3d

В списке создаваемых обьектов пропала вкладка UI. Вот фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идее она должна быть между Video и Camera, но ее там нет. Как это исправить?

В новом проекте все работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а что пропало то?

Comment: @Methorn Вкладка UI с выпадающим списком обьектов

Comment: Ты пробовал нажимать не на Canvas?